# Convert XSD without single root Node to XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm looking for an easy way to generate a sample XML file from an XSD that do not contain a single root node.

Comment: How would you have created your sample XML file if there had been only one element defined in the XSD?

Comment: Any valid XML document MUST contain one and exactly one root node - otherwise it's at best an XML fragment.....

Comment: I think the OP probably has a schema that allows two alternative root elements?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that without specifying the root. XML Schema is designed such that all top-level `xs:element` can represent the root node, so you cannot distinguish it given the schema alone. You'll have to ask user to explicitly specify the `xs:element` he wants to treat as root.

Answer (score 1):

If your file doesn't have an xml declaration at the top, a single root node, and follow all other XML rules, it's not XML, its a text file.  You can't treat any old text files like XML.